# R: Hide some parts of ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to plot a facetted box plot of some data, including the outliers with colours, a mark showing group mean (created with `stat_summary`), as well as a horizontal line marking the average value of the facet group. I would like to have a legend for the horizontal line (denoting the facet group average) and the box plot mark (denoting the group means within each facet). I've tried quite a few approaches thus far, from testing out the `show.legend` argument in every geom, fiddling with different inputs to `scale_colour_manual` (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291849/ggplot-how-to-plot-an-independent-legend-how-to-legend-only-certain-things) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315677/r-ggplot-add-legend-manually) SO post), the [`new_scale_color` function of the `ggnewscale` package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491072/legend-with-only-some-series-of-data-ggplot-r), or [overriding the aesthetics with the `guides` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806424/removing-elements-from-the-legend-in-ggplot-when-plotting-facets-with-multiple-a).

Below is the plot so far, along with the code to make it (using the `msleep` dataset). I've successfully been able to get the desired legends of the two stats (`geom_hline` and `stat_summary` - marked in green). However, this comes along with another legend of the variables I'm faceting on (marked in red), and I cannot figure out how to hide only this part of the legend, but keep the ones I'm interested in.

[image: Boxplot-msleep-SO]

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggsci)

df <- as_tibble(msleep) %>% 
    mutate(bodywt_log10 = log10(bodywt)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = c(sleep_total, awake, bodywt_log10),
                 names_to = 'stat', values_to = 'value') %>% 
    select(-c('sleep_rem', 'sleep_cycle', 'brainwt', 'bodywt')) %>% 
    mutate(stat = factor(stat, levels = unique(stat))) %>% 
    group_by(stat) %>% 
    mutate(mean = mean(value)) %>% 
    group_by(stat, order) %>% 
    mutate(Q1 = quantile(value, 1/4, na.rm = T),
           Q2 = quantile(value, 2/4, na.rm = T),
           Q3 = quantile(value, 3/4, na.rm = T),
           IQR = IQR(value, na.rm = T),
           upper.limit=Q3+1.5*IQR, 
           lower.limit=Q1-1.5*IQR)

outlier_dat <- df %>%
    filter(value > upper.limit | value < lower.limit)

pal <- pal_npg('nrc')(3)

df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = order, y = value)) + 
    geom_boxplot(show.legend = F, outlier.shape = NA, aes(col = stat)) +
    geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, show.legend = F, aes(fill = stat)) +
    stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = 'point', shape = 18, size = 3, aes(col = 'group_mean'), show.legend = T) +
    facet_grid(stat~., scales = 'free', labeller = as_labeller(
        c(sleep_total = 'Total sleep', awake = 'Time awake', bodywt_log10 = 'log10(Bodyweight)'))) + 
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean, col = 'mean'), size = .75, lty = 2, show.legend = T) +
    scale_fill_npg() + 
    scale_colour_manual(name = NULL, values = c('mean' = 'black', 'group_mean' = 'gray10', 
                                                'sleep_total' = pal[1], 'awake' = pal[2], 'bodywt_log10' = pal[3]),
                        breaks = c('mean', 'group_mean'), labels = c('Overall mean', 'Group mean'),
                        guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c('dashed', 'blank'), shape =  c(NA, 18)))) +
    geom_point(data = outlier_dat, aes(col = stat), size = 2, show.legend = F)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following:

```
+ guides(fill = "none")
```

You have one legend (guide) for each aes mapping - your faceting variables are a fill scale (each facet has a different fill colour) whereas the means are a color/colour scale (i.e. the line/point colour rather than fill).  Setting the guide for the "fill" colour to "none" removes it from the plot.

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
df + guides(fill="none")
```